# Python from pathlib import Path crash into QGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-processing, python-script-tool

I'm creating a custom Python script inside QGIS Processing in Mac OS system,
I encountered a serious error cause a crash of QGIS application.
If in my Python script I use this library:

```
from pathlib import Path
```

QGIS crash

I partially solve the issue using this:

```
import ntpath
```

and Work fine.
Someone have a similar experience about?

Comment: Can you launch QGIS in a terminal and just enter that line in its Python Console to crash it? If so, does it print something to the terminal?

Comment: in Python console inside Qgis app it work fine.
Qgis app crash when I use pathlib inside a QgisProcessing script

Comment: Can you share a minimal script that triggers this?

Comment: @bugmenot123 The code is in my repo project, [here](https://github.com/gianfrancodp/metpetools/tree/main/Qgis%20processing%20script)

Comment: That's a lot of code unrelated to the import, can you minimize and still get a crash?

Comment: I've uploaded file [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gianfrancodp/metpetools/main/Qgis%20processing%20script/shp2html_Qgis_processing_TEST.py)

Comment: Minimal would be something like https://pastebin.com/raw/8eviJ3tx , does that trigger the same crash?

Answer (score 0):

I partially solve the issue using this:

```
import ntpath
```

and Work fine. Someone have a similar experience about?